# Laravel 5.4 get every day of the current week using Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I've been using the syntax `Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()` and `Carbon::now()->endOfWeek()` for awhile now.

It returns the first day of the week which is the date of `Monday` and the last day of the week which is the date of `Sunday`. *(I don't know why it wasn't Sunday and Saturday)*

But now, I want to get every `day` of the `current week`. So what's left is the dates of `Tuesday`, `Wednesday`, `Thursday`, `Friday`, and `Saturday`.

Here's my exact syntax on getting `Monday` and `Sunday`.

```
$monday = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek();
$sunday = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can progress through the week with `addDay()`.

```
$monday = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek();
$tuesday = $monday->copy()->addDay();
$wednesday = $tuesday->copy()->addDay();
```

You can also check which day of the week you have.

```
$wednesday === Carbon::WEDNESDAY; // true
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the current week of a spesific day  try with this 

 1.- create a carbon day with the day that you need

```
$carbaoDay = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->day); 
//spesific day format 2000-01-00
```

2 aftert into a for loop just push a day

```
$carbaoDay->startOfWeek()->addDay($i)->format('Y-m-d');
$carbaoDay->startOfWeek() /// always monday
->addDay($i)->format('Y-m-d'); //$i =1 push: 2000-01-01 ,;//$i =2 push: 2000-01-02
```

```
$carbaoDay = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->day); //spesific day

$week = []; 
for ($i=0; $i <7 ; $i++) {
    $week[] = $carbaoDay->startOfWeek()->addDay($i)->format('Y-m-d');//push the current day and plus the mount of $i 
}

output:
    array:7 [
  0 => "2020-01-06"
  1 => "2020-01-07"
  2 => "2020-01-08"
  3 => "2020-01-09"
  4 => "2020-01-10"
  5 => "2020-01-11"
  6 => "2020-01-12"
]
```